# SwiftUI Drag on iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I've implemented a very simple Drag and Drop interface like this:

```
Text("Drag me")
    .onDrag{return NSItemProvider(object: "DragID" as NSString)}
```

When running the app as a Mac app I can drag the Text element just fine, but on iOS simulator / device (running iOS 16.4 and 16.3) - no drag and drop...